# How to return datatypes using CSV Reader API in Java

Tags: java, csv

I am working with `.csv` file that contains multiple columns (variables) .
Each of these variables might be either `Decimal` , `VARCHAR` , or `Date` type .

If a column contains **all** numbers , then it is `Decimal`; if **all** dates then `Date` ; otherwise the default is `VARCHAR`.

---

I know one way to determine this by checking **EACH** value in the data set .

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader (new FileReader(.....));
        String row [] = reader.readNext();
            while ((row = reader.readNext()) !=null ) {
                // I go through EACH value to see if it is `Decimal` , `VARCHAR` , or `Date` 
            }
        }
        reader.close();
```

However the above approach is slow .

**Is there any better way or Command in CSV Reader to do this fast ?**
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to check a subset of the column and then if that subset is a certain datatype, assume that the rest are the same datatype? Or if you have a column that is a large number of `Date`s and there is one non-date value it is automatically a `VARCHAR`?

Since you state in your question that

```
If a column contains all numbers , then it is Decimal, if all date then Date , otherwise the default is VARCHAR.
```

You have to check every member in the column if there are 1000 Decimal members and 1 Date at the end you'd have to check the whole column to know it is of type `VARCHAR`. One thing that you could do to optimize is to keep track of the datatypes present in the column and if there are >= 2 datatypes, terminate for that column and return `VARCHAR` as that column's datatype.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 This is correct. If there is at least one `non Date` value in a column although all other values are `Date` it is `VARCHAR`. I was hoping that `CSV Reader` had some shortcut for this